# OpenRDF/Sesame don't delivers an Model

Tags: java, rdf, sesame

I was using FUSEKI and now changed to OpenRDF/Sesame.

Everything works fine, i have just one problem.
In one method i need to get back the complete database of my repositori in a Model. The Method looks like this:

```
  private static Model getRepositoryModel() throws ResourceRepositoryException{
  String queryString = "DESCRIBE * WHERE {?r ?s ?p}";
  Model currentModel = QueryExecuter.executeSparqlDescribeQuery(queryString);
  return currentModel; }

public static Model executeSparqlDescribeQuery(String queryString) throws ResourceRepositoryException {
Model resultModel = null;
try{
  QueryExecution qe = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService(SESAME_SERVICE_QUERY, queryString);
  resultModel = qe.execDescribe();
} catch(QueryExceptionHTTP | QueryParseException e){
  throw new ResourceRepositoryException(e.getMessage());
}
correctNsPrefixes(resultModel);
return resultModel;}
```

But i don't actually get a Model back. But in SPARQL you have to get one back if you call this method. It also worked with FUSEKI.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. This code is using Jena/Fuseki to execute a SPARQL query, not Sesame. If you are having problems getting a query result while using Sesame, actually show the Sesame code you're using.

Comment: Why are you so sure that it's still Fuseki-Code?
All this Method do is send an Query to an URL on which the sesame server is listening.
I dont have the complete Sesame code available, because i deployed the sesame workbench and server as 2 WARs on my wildfly-server.
and i only have the 2 wars because my chef patched an bug in sesame and send me the 2 files to work with.

The "executeSparqlDescribeQuery" is sending the query to (for example) http://localhostlocalhost:8080/openrdf-workbench/repositories/TEST". If i send a normal "SELECT"-Query i get the right answer back.

Comment: Well I'm not 100% sure it's Fuseki code, but as I am one of the Sesame developers, I'm pretty sure it's not Sesame code :)

Answer (score 1):

From your comments I gather that you are using Jena to query a remote Sesame Server (it wasn't clear earlier that that was what you were doing, I initially thought you had switched your own client code over to use Sesame as well but had posted the wrong/old code). Although this is a slightly unconventional setup (most people using Sesame Server also use the Sesame APIs to actually query/access it), it certainly should be possible.

Apparently, however, you are using something like this as the Sesame SPARQL endpoint URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/openrdf-workbench/repositories/test
```

(assuming your repository is named 'test').

This is not the correct URL to use. It *should* be:

```
http://localhost:8080/openrdf-sesame/repositories/test
```

Notice the difference: not "openrdf-**workbench**", but "openrdf-**sesame**".

The workbench is a client UI for a Sesame Server, it is *not* intended to be used as the SPARQL endpoint itself. The fact that it apparently works if you use it for SELECT-queries is just an unfortunate side effect. It is not intended to be used as such.

Comment: First of all: Thx for your Support Jeen!
I know its not the common way to communicate with sesame, but it was the only way because i only had the 2 war files.
I also knew that it has to be "sesame" and not workbench, but when i used sesame all my Junit-tests failed because there came no answer back.With 'workbench' it luckily worked.
Will later try to change it back to sesame and see if i can find the error.